# How to get notification about new major releases delivery on IBM Cloud APIs/Services

Tags: ibm-cloud

At present, seems customer can only check the release notes manually from cloud platform -> status page after it's officially delivered.

1. Is there any way to get change log/release notes on IBM Cloud different components (e.g. APIs/Services/etc) ahead of the delivery date? If so customer may have enough time to evaluate the impact on coming releases, and take corresponding action to avoid any integration failure.
2. Any way to subscribe the cloud platform release notes? It would be helpful to get the notification at the first time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to [Release Notes in the IBM Cloud status](https://cloud.ibm.com/status/release-notes). There is either an option for RSS feed or it should be possible to set up some other notification. [See the docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/get-support?topic=get-support-viewing-cloud-status).

For announcements of upcoming changes, you can subscribe to the [announcements in the IBM Cloud status](https://cloud.ibm.com/status/announcement) or to the [announcements blog](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/).

Comment: Thanks! So we couldn't be notified with the details of new release before the released date?
Will the new release be delivered on test cloud firstly before it goes alive on production environment?

Comment: For important changes, there are announcements posted. See the updated answer. Please upvote it and mark as answered